# GTM server-side tagging: compression

Tags: google-tag-manager

We set up server-side tagging using the docker-container google provides in its "[manual setup guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/manual-setup-guide)"

Everything is working fine, but all request against the tagging-server are answered without any compression: no gzip, no deflate, no br, just plain text.

Is there anything we are missing? The docs provided by google do not give any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2022, this is not possible. We used a cdn that gives us content compression.